# GS Papersize form PDF

Tags: batch-file, pdf, ghostscript

I want to Create a Batch Printing with Ghostscript on a printer which can do Papersizes from A0 to A4.
The Papersize for printing comes from the PDF-Document. That means a A0-Pdf-File should keep it's papersize for printing to a A0 paper.
Now GS always resizes the document to its defaults for example A4

So i don't know how i can say GS: "Read the Papersize of the document and print the same"

My command looks like this:

"Path to GS\gswin32c.exe" -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="\spool\\print-server\Name of my printer" -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE "\server\folder\123456-01.pdf"

Comment: sort them by size using e.g. identify or another tool, and then batch the groups of same size for manual printer election  - easier than 50 printer dialogs anyway

Answer (score 1):

as far as I am aware Ghostscript does not resize its output, even when using the mswinpr2 device, but it is possible that it does. However, it won't be resizing it to the GS default, it will be resizing it to the printer default.

The mswinpr2 device can't change the media size selected in the printer, so it print to the default printer settings.

You can't send PDF files of a range of sized media to the mswinpr2 device and have it select different media from the printer.

No doubt the device could be extended to do so, and you *can* have a print dialog pop up and select different criteria there